# How can I have one th for multiple tds?

Tags: html

I have n amount of tds inside of 1 tr.  I would like to have a th at the top of the table which spans all n tds.  Can this be done?

```
<table>
  <th>Header</th>
  <tr>
   <td> 1 / n </td><td> 2 / n </td><td >3 / n </td>...
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `colspan` attribute as defined on [table cells](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.6). Note that a `th` should be nested in a `tr` as well.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="n">Header</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td> 1 / n </td><td> 2 / n </td><td >3 / n </td>...
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is in fact what I ended up doing.  Except I had to set it with javascript since it was a variable based on the width of the user's viewing area.  I just added a script right after the th was defined and then used document.getelementbyid().style.colSpan to set the varying size

Answer (score 0):

there is a solution but it won't work on all browsers; `colspan='0'`

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="0">Header</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td> 1 / n </td><td> 2 / n </td><td >3 / n </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This does NOT work when the table-layout CSS property is set to fixed, also this is not a good markup practice :P

Comment: Not-cross browser, not semantic, non-standard, doesn't work with certain CSS properties. Why even post it?

Comment: the same answer was given twice before on stackoverflow. [1st](http://alturl.com/p6mcd) [2nd](http://alturl.com/of8ti), also [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp) mentioned it so i thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: see if i didn't mentioned this i wouldn't have knew about w3fools.com, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a header that appears very first in the table and spans *all* columns, the odds are that it’s not a header cell for all the columns but a caption for the entire table. In that case, the logical markup is to use the `<caption>Header</caption>`. It is written before any of the rows (and *not* wrapped inside a `<tr>` element). It will appear in normal text style by default, so you might want to set e.g. `caption { font-weight: bold }` in CSS.

Comment: Yes, this is what I had hacked th to do.  But I actually <.<   >.> didn't know about caption!  Thank you for the new info :)